# Primality criterion for generalized Fermat numbers similar to the LLT ?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I asked this question on mathstackexchange but didn't get any answer .

> Definition 1 :
>
> Let $F_n(b) $ be a generalized Fermat number of the form :
>
> $F_n(b) = b^{2^n}+1 $ , where $b$ is a positive even integer .
>
> Definition 2 :
>
> Let $T_n(S_{i-1}) $ be a Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind , i.e.
>
> $T_n(S_{i-1}) =  2^{-1} \cdot \left(\left(S_{i-1}+\sqrt{S^2_{i-1}-1}\right)^n+\left(S_{i-1}-\sqrt{S^2_{i-1}-1}\right)^n\right ) $

How to prove following statements :

Example 1 :

Let's define sequence $S_i $ as :

$ S_i = T_{78} (S_{i-1} ) \text{ with }  S_{0} = 6 $

I have found that :

$ F_1(156) \mid S_2  , ~ F_4(156) \mid S_{30} , ~ F_5(156) \mid S_{62} $

Also , no composite  $ F_n(156) $ up to $n= 10 $ divides corresponding $S_i $ .

> Conjecture :
>
> $F_{n}(156) , (n \geq 1)   \text{ is a prime iff }  F_n(156) \mid S_{2^{n+1}-2} $

Example 2 :

Let's define sequence $S_i $ as :

$ S_i = T_{18} (S_{i-1} ) \text{ with }  S_{0} = 8 $

I have found that :

$ F_2(288) \mid S_{17}  , ~ F_3(288) \mid S_{37} , ~ F_4(288) \mid S_{77} $

Also , no composite $F_{n}(288) $ up to $ n=10 $ divides corresponding $S_i $ .

> Conjecture :
>
> $F_{n}(288) , (n \geq 1)  \text{ is a prime iff } F_n(288) \mid S_{5 \cdot 2^n-3} $

Example 3 :

Let's define sequence $S_i $ as :

$S_i = T_{2222}(S_{i-1}) \text{ with } S_{0}=4 $

I have found that :

$ F_1(4444) \mid S_{2} , ~ F_2(4444) \mid S_{6} , ~ F_4(4444) \mid S_{30} $

Also , no composite $F_{n}(4444) $ up to $n=10 $ divides corresponding $S_i $ .

> Conjecture :
>
> $F_{n}(4444) , (n \geq 1 )  \text{ is a prime iff } F_n(4444) \mid S_{2^{n+1}-2} $

P.S.

I am interested in hints (not full solution) .